# After insert trigger rounding total when it should not, after insert works OK

Tags: triggers, rounding

I have an after insert trigger and an after update trigger on a transaction table with charges and payments.  The triggers update the account balance with the total of the payments less the charges to give a balance.  The trigger works great for the after update trigger, but the after insert trigger is rounding the account balance.  The code for both triggers is identical as it was cut & pasted.

The code is:
BEGIN
declare charges decimal(7,2);
declare payments decimal(7,2);
select sum(amount) into charges
from transactions
where transaction_type = 'C'
and official_id = new.official_id;
select sum(amount) into payments
from transactions
where transaction_type = 'P'
and official_id = new.official_id;
update officials
set account_balance = ifnull(payments,0) - ifnull(charges,0)
where id_officials = new.official_id;

END

I can't see why this is happening nor how to get around it.

Thanks!
Dave

I was expecting the same result from both triggers